# Custom Slider widget with wxPython

Tags: python, slider, wxpython, custom-controls, wxwidgets

I would need to make a

```
slider = wx.Slider(self, 100, 25, 1, 100, (30, 60), (250, -1), wx.SL_HORIZONTAL)
```

[image]

have a transparent background (because it appears on a panel which has a non-uniform background).

More generally, **how is it possible possible to change its look to something like this ?**

[image]

(I am open to use `.png` files for the widget elements, if needed.)

Answer (score 4):

No, wxWidgets uses native look and feel and native controls under Windows look like your top screenshot, not the bottom one. If you want to have a custom look, you really need to use a custom control.

Comment: Ok so I need to create my own control by subclassing `wx.PyControl` (or another one? which one?) and do the binding myself for moving the slider image ?
But the problem will be the same : how to have transparency for `wx.PyControl` ?

Comment: Look at `samples/erase/erase.cpp` in wxWidgets distribution. Be warned that child window transparency is unfortunately not supporte under all platforms.

Comment: So what is the good solution (working on all platform) to have a `wx.PyControl` widget which will not have a rectangle black or white background, but rather will be blended into its parent window ?

Comment: I'm okay for building a custom widget : 1 `wx.StaticBitmap` for the horizontal line    + 1 Bitmap for the circle moving part (what kind of `wx` object for that ? Not a `StaticBitmap` I imagine...)... How to make that this circle moving part is circle and not rectangular ?